# Torquing tie rod castle nut to proper specification pushes it past cotter pin hole

Tags: ford, tie-rod

So I'm replacing the tie rod ends on my 2008 Ford fusion and torquing the castle nut to the proper specification, 37 foot pounds appears like it will push the castle nut past the cotter pin hole. I'm not sure if this is correct it seems wrong to me, should I continue to torque the castle nut, or leave it where the cotter pin can hold it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning a castle nut with a torque spec to a cotter pin hole](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5986/aligning-a-castle-nut-with-a-torque-spec-to-a-cotter-pin-hole)

Comment: Continue turning until the next slot lines up. Never back the nut off to align slot.